# log4j: File getting created but not getting written

Tags: java, log4j

I am using Log4j file appender having the below configuration:

```
log4j.logger.com.atpl=INFO,ABW
log4j.appender.ABW=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.ABW.File=c://atpl-platform-web//atplABW.txt
log4j.appender.ABW.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.ABW.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.ABW.layout.ConversionPattern= [%d] [%t] [%-5p] [%c] ==> %m%n
```

The file is getting created at the given location all right. The file is getting locked once I start the server. But when I try to log data into that file, its not working.

```
private static final Logger FILE_LOGGER = Logger
    .getLogger(TreeDemoAction.class);

FILE_LOGGER.info(gson.toJson(rootNode));
```

Also below is the server log on restart.

```
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in   production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin;C:\Tomcat 6.0\bin
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:15 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8084
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 363 ms
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:15 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\atpl-platform-web\WEB-INF\lib\servlet.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'atpl-platform-web' = [C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\atpl-platform-web\]
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Log4J from [C:\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\atpl-platform-web\WEB-INF\log4j.properties]
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
 INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
 AbandonedObjectPool is used (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@84f665)
    LogAbandoned: false
    RemoveAbandoned: true
    RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 60
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:22 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8084
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:22 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:22 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/15  config=null
Nov 2, 2012 3:47:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7177 ms
```

Can anyone guide me with what is wrong here? am i missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: side note: I think you do not need double slash in file path

Comment: What is the FQN of TreeDemoAction ?

Comment: @Nishant tried with single slashes as well. no probs in creating file. writing is the issue

Comment: @PeterMmm: am sorry, FQN?? as far as I understand do you want to know this : com.platform.web.action

Comment: Yes, and this has no common prefix with com.atpl ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you get the logger package wrong

```
log4j.logger.com.platform.web=INFO,ABW
```

Answer (score 0):

`log4j.logger.com.atpl=INFO,ABW` is OK.
Try following code:

```
log4j.appender.ABW.File=/atpl-platform-web/atplABW.txt
```